# Hindi Data in SQL Server 2005 database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2005, excel, hindi

I am developing a windows application which need to insert data from a MS Excel file which contains a lot of data in two different languages, English and Hindi. I am able to import the English data easily but while importing the Hindi data the its been converted to some English text.

I am using NVARCHAR as datatype for all my fields. Arial Font for English and SHUSHA font for Hindi Language. In Excel the data is correctly shown. But in SSMS and my Applicaton the Hindi data is shown as some english characters.

Kindly help !

Comment: How are you importing the data?  Excel stores cell contents as Unicode, but some languages, so example Classic ASP, don't handle Unicode correctly?

Comment: I am using OleDbDataReader to get data from the excel file. then populating the sql table row wise.

Answer (score 1):

NVARCHAR is definitely able to store Hindi Unicode characters. There must be something wrong with your SQL insertion code, i.e maybe you are using a `SqlParameter` with datatype `SqlDbType.VarChar` when you are inserting. Posting this code would clarify.

Comment: I am reading data from excel using OleDbDataReader. then putting data in each field in different variables and inserting the record in SQL table using those variables.

Comment: I have got it, I have to prefix N before every data I need to insert to the tables.

But again I am getting a strange problem. On Windows 7 machine both SSMS and My application shows the Hindi data in correct format. But when I use Win XP, only Boxes are shows every where in stead of Hinid data.

Can you help!

Comment: What if you try "Results to text" in SSMS? I've noticed this is more reliable for displaying Unicode characters. Not sure why. Maybe it uses a different font?